# Angular cloud foundry deployment

Tags: angular, cloud-foundry

Do you know about the best practice, how to deploy Angular CLI app to the cloud foundry like [CF](https://login.run.pivotal.io/home)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [jHipster](https://jhipster.github.io) as a example. jHipster has [micorservices](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/) including those of angular or angularJS. jHipster is a very mature project and will help you learn some of the best practices.